# How to prevent circular references in a linked list in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, linked-list, circular-reference, adjacency-list

The table and the valid data is like this:

```
| id | after_id |
| -- | -------- |
| a  | null     |
| b  | a        |
| c  | b        |
| d  | c        |
```

And the goal is to prevent something like that:

```
| id | after_id |
| -- | -------- |
| a  | d        | <- 'a' now follows 'd', creating a loop.
| b  | a        |
| c  | b        |
| d  | c        |
```

---

It doesn't seem to be possible to solve this without storing some additional info that will help to create a constraint. But I can't figure out what info will help. Postgresql has `EXCLUDE` constraint and I thought maybe it would be possible to use overlaping operator somehow. Don't have a clue how to solve this but I have a feeling it will require updating too many rows which will defeat the whole point of storing a sequence in a linked list.

---

UPD:
The idea is ensure the integrity of the list on a database level, not application level. Another example of a not valid state:

```
| id | after_id |
| -- | -------- |
| a  | null     |
| b  | d        | <- updated
| c  | b        |
| d  | c        |
```

Or another:

```
| id | after_id |
| -- | -------- |
| a  | null     |
| b  | d        | <- updated: followed 'a', now follows 'd'
| c  | b        |
| d  | c        |
| e  | a        | <- updated: followed 'd', now follows 'a', unique constraint on after_id will not be violated this way
```

Comment: There is no way to solve this with a constraint.

Comment: why do dating the NULL anyway, check if it is NULL and then block the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This article](https://blog.mergify.io/cycle-detection-in-postgresql/) seems related to your question. It talks about avoiding circles and sets up a trigger to do so.

Also, if you are looking at PostgreSQL 14, there can be a [native query to detect cycles](https://www.depesz.com/2021/02/04/waiting-for-postgresql-14-search-and-cycle-clauses/)

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, unfortunately that doesn't really solve this. As Laurenz Albe points out in this article https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/triggers-to-enforce-constraints/

Comment: Marked this as an answer as the most helpful :)